# C Prog.: Structure as argument of function?

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to to create structure "Date of birth", and function that will assign values to the structure, and i am wondering is that possible to do that somehow like this:

(PS. I am constantly getting error "Argument list syntax error", for 2nd and 23th lines.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void input (dob_st *);
int main ()
{
    typedef struct
    {
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;
    }
    dob_st;

    dob_st date;
    dob_st *p;
    p=&date;
    input (*p);
    printf("%02i.",p->day);
    printf("%02i.",p->month);
    printf("%i.",p->year);

    return 0;
}
void upis (dob_st *p)
{
    printf ("Date of birth:\nDay?\n");
    scanf ("%i",&(p->day));
    printf ("Month?\n");
    scanf ("%i",&(p->month));
    printf ("Year?\n");
    scanf ("%i",&(p->year));
}
```

Comment: Tanks you a lot! About "upis", i've commented it on Artur's post, and that is because i was translating it from serbian, and forgot to translate that.

I thought that i can't declare structure outside of main function... :) Now everything looks logical...

Answer (score 12):

I think you're getting this because the definition of `dob_st` is local only to `main` -- it's not defined outside this method. The `void input (dob_st *);` method has no way to know what the `dob_st` is, and it's called `upis` later on, not `input`, which is probably another error.

Answer (score 3):

Some things: You should declare your structure outside of the main function, and before the prototype of the input function.

You should also pass to input a pointer to a dob_st structure and not a structure itself: The possible code now as

```
dob_st date;
dob_st *p;
p=&date;
input (*p);
```

should be

```
dob_st date;
input (&date);
```

and the output be later based on date directly.

PD: Is the upis function be meant to be the input function?

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the name of the function from 'input' to 'upis'.

You also need to define dob_st outside the main() function.

Answer (score 0):

p is a pointer, so the argument should be "input(p)"  in stead of "inuput(*p)". Using *p deferenences the pointer, and it is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In standard C, you write "struct dob_st *p" instead of simply "dob_st *p".
Also make sure that you declare the struct dob_st *before* you first use it.